# Spotify Access Code POST request returning 'Failed to load resource'

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, spotify

So I am trying to create an app using the Spotify API to get Playlist details but I'm struggling to get the Access Code through VSCode. I have Postman setup where I can get the Access for now and I have managed to successfully created a JavaScript function that allows me to get playlist information but for some reason I just can't get a function working in JS to get the Access Code.

Please take a look at my code so far and see if there is anything in there that could be causing the issue.

**My Code**

```
    const client_id = '****************';
    const client_secret = '****************';
    const base64 = btoa(client_id + ":" + client_secret);

    // get auth code from URL param
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const authCode = urlParams.get('code');

    try {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';
        
        var params = JSON.stringify({
            'grant_type' : 'authorization_code',
            'code' : authCode,
            'redirect_uri' : 'http://localhost:8080/spotify-master/_inc/playlists.inc.php',
            'scope' : 'playlist-modify-public playlist-read-private playlist-modify-private'
        })
        http.open('POST', url, true);

        //Send the proper header information along with the request
        http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        http.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Basic ' + base64);
        
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }
        }

        console.log(params);

        http.send(params);
    }
    catch (e){
        console.log(e);
    }
```